# PHP email shows html source code in Apple Mail

Tags: php, html-email

I am sending an html email and the email shows perfectly fine everywhere except it shows the source code instead of the content in Apple mail.

Here is what I've done:

```
$to = "";
$subject = "";
$message = '
<html>
<head>
<title>New Inquiry From Quick Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#F4F3F4">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 15px;">Name:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 15px;">Last Name:</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
';

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: "<support@mydomain>"' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Note: The HTML in my "message" variable above is just sample. I have a valid HTML in my actual development. I think I am doing something wrong with my headers.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: how about trying valid html

Comment: The HTML above is just a sample. I have perfectly a fine HTML in actually development. something should be wrong with me headers. Thanks

Comment: help me debug this code, its not the real code, just some what similar - sigh, no thanks.

Comment: ok, may not be the problem but that is still not valid html- which is a good place to start

Comment: Your script works perfectly fine when I test it on my server... I get a mail with this table in a grey background color, not source code. Maybe something with your PHP mail() function?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, it it will help, but I would try to use phpmailer class, as it makes headers more accurate (google for download phpmailer class).
Also you can send e-mails using g-mail smtp server (google for php send email through gmail).